# An API access token is required to use Mapbox GL

Tags: mapbox-gl

I am trying to implement a map on my  Rails application through mapbox gl. I followed all the steps but the map is not displayed and I get this error on the console : An API access token is required to use Mapbox GL. I actually set the key on my .env file . These is all the process to implement the map :

```
- geocoder.rb

Geocoder.configure(
  # [...]
  units: :km, # defaults to miles (:mi)
  # [...]
)

- shop.rb

  

      class Shop < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :user
      has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
      geocoded_by :address
      after_validation :geocode, if: :will_save_change_to_address?
    
      def confirmed_orders
        self.products.joins(:cart).where(carts: {status: "confirmed"})
      end
    
      def past_confirmed_orders
        self.confirmed_orders.joins(:cart).where("carts.pick_up_date < ?" , Date.today)
      end
    
      def upcoming_confirmed_orders
        self.confirmed_orders.joins(:cart).where("carts.pick_up_date >= ?" , Date.today)
      end
    end

- Shopcontroller

    def index
    @shops = Shop.all
    @markers = @shops.geocoded.map do |shop|
      {
        lat: shop.latitude,
        lng: shop.longitude
      }
    end
  end


- _index.html.erb (MAPBOX_API_KEY is defined in my .env file)

    <div id="map"
     style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"
     data-markers="<%= @markers.to_json %>"
     data-mapbox-api-key="<%= ENV['MAPBOX_API_KEY'] %>">
</div>
   

- init_mapbox.js

    import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

const buildMap = (mapElement) => {
  mapboxgl.accessToken = mapElement.dataset.mapboxApiKey;
  return new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10'
  });
};

const addMarkersToMap = (map, markers) => {
  markers.forEach((marker) => {
    new mapboxgl.Marker()
      .setLngLat([ marker.lng, marker.lat ])
      .addTo(map);
  });
};

const fitMapToMarkers = (map, markers) => {
  const bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds();
  markers.forEach(marker => bounds.extend([ marker.lng, marker.lat ]));
  map.fitBounds(bounds, { padding: 70, maxZoom: 15 });
};

const initMapbox = () => {
  const mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
  if (mapElement) {
    const map = buildMap(mapElement);
    const markers = JSON.parse(mapElement.dataset.markers);
    addMarkersToMap(map, markers);
    fitMapToMarkers(map, markers);
  }
};

export { initMapbox };


- application.js

    import { initMapbox } from '../plugins/init_mapbox';


document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {

  initMapbox();
});


Thank you in advance for your time.
```

Comment: Sorry for the ugly format as well

Comment: If you're getting an error that "An API access token is required to use Mapbox GL" you should check whether you successfully connected your .env file and token to your project. It sounds like that may not be working properly.